# Java "implement interface"?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I know "implement interface" means: A class implement a interface.
Now I met a puzzle in Android Studio (In IntelliJ IDEA, there has a similar doubts.):
Note the following picture:
When Child implement the Interface, and override the method fun2, there will be a specific icon on the left.But the Parent don't implement the Interface, why an same icon appear?

[image]

Bigger picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK4H1.png)

Comment: Never link to external sites. Always put up all relevant code here.

Comment: @GhostCat OP asked specifically about the icons and he has to put a picture of it. He doesn't have the rep to upload a picture therefore he had to link to an external site.

Comment: This question is about IDE，if not link to external sites show the screenshot, no one will know what the problem is。If you have time, please review the question.

Comment: If you hover your mouse cursor over the icon, what does the tool tip that appears say?

Answer (score 2):

In the full version of IntelliJ with the 3 example classes you posted above, the icon you refer to has hover text:

*Implements method in Interface via sub-class Child*

In other words IntelliJ is smart enough to see the association between the interface and the inheritance structure.

Why does it do this? Well if you remove the definition of `fun1` from `Child` class, then `fun1` is of course visible in `Child` class via inheritance from `Parent`, thereby fulfilling the requirement to implement `Interface`.